# File/Folder sorting by semi-complex names

Tags: windows, batch-file

I need to sort a series of images into folders by part of their names.
The only thing consistent is a series of numbers after an underscore.
I would like to use the content before the underscore as the folder name.
The problem is that some of the images have an underscore in the name.
I'm just not getting the variables right...

Currently using:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%A in (*.jpg) do (
   echo file found  %%A
   for /f "delims=" %%B in ("%%A") do set fname=%%~nB
   for /f "delims=" %%C in ("%%A") do set fextn=%%~xC
   for /f "tokens=1* delims=_" %%D in ("!fname!") do set folname=%%D
   echo folder name !folname!
   if not exist "!folname!" (
      echo Folder !folname! does not exist, creating
      md "!folname!"
   ) else (
      echo Folder !folname! exists
   )
   echo Moving file %%A to folder !folname!
   move "%%A" "!folname!"
   )
echo Finished
pause
```

Examples of problematic names:

```
a_t_r_a_v__a_83563614_2994781403891160_6736610473828214002_n.jpg
alexa_vn10s1ty429_81834750_1570208686488587_1442450484794514255_n.jp
```

More common names:

```
shurra.m.lance_96141088_342661823370490_6342263806980952485_n.jpg
anu.m0111_104134441_573701159868969_589828829350351913_n.jpg
```

Currently hoping to get these turned into folders as:

```
a_t_r_a_v__a
alexa_vn10s1ty429
shurra.m.lance
anu.m0111
```

Just not getting it to ignore the right underscores.

Thanks for your time in advance.  I am learning so much here but I guess I'm just missing the last piece.

Comment: Are there spaces in the filename or can we assume there are none?

Comment: No spaces.  Just underscores and periods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a trivial task, but I think I have found a solution (see all the explanatory `rem` remarks):

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem /* Loop through matching files; `findstr` additionally filters them, so only
rem    items containing an underscore followed by a decimal digit are processed;
rem    exclamation marks are prohibited in the portion behind the prefix: */
for /F "delims= eol=|" %%F in ('
    dir /B /A:-D-H-S "*_*.jpg" ^| findstr /RIC:"[^_]_[0123456789][^!]*\.jpg$"
') do (
    rem // Store current file name:
    set "FILE=%%F" & set "TEST=%%F"
    rem // Toggle delayed expansion to avoid problems with exclamation marks:
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    rem // Define ascending and descending number sequences for the next loop:
    for %%J in ("0,1,9" "9,-1,0") do (
        rem // Loop through all decimal digits, increasing, then decreasing:
        for /L %%I in (%%~J) do (
            rem // Find `_` plus the current digit, remove everything in front:
            if not "!TEST:*_%%I=!"=="!TEST!" set "NAME=!TEST:*_%%I=_%%I!"
        )
        rem /* Remove previously end of file name to get the desired prefix
        rem    (at this point exclamation marks could cause problems): */
        for /F "delims= eol=|" %%E in ("!NAME!") do set "TEST=!TEST:%%E=!"
    )
    rem // Create desired directory and move current file into it:
    ECHO md "!TEST!" 2> nul
    ECHO move /Y "!FILE!" "!TEST!\"
    endlocal
)

endlocal
exit /B
```

After having tested for the correct output, **remove the upper-case `ECHO` commands**.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simpler (and faster) method:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "digits=0123456789"

for %%A in (*.jpg) do (

   set "fname=%%A"

   rem Initialize "first digit after an underscore"
   set "firstDigit="

   rem Split name at underscores
   for %%a in ("!fname:_= " "!") do (
      if not defined firstDigit (
         set "part=%%~a"
         rem Check if first char in part is in "digits"
         for /F %%b in ("!part:~0,1!") do if "!digits:%%b=X!" neq "%digits%" set "firstDigit=%%b"
      )
   )

   rem Split name at "underscore+firstDigit"
   for /F %%a in ("!firstDigit!") do for /F %%b in ("!fname:_%%a= !") do set "folname=%%b"

   echo Moving file %%A to folder !folname!

)
```

Output example:

```
Moving file a_t_r_a_v__a_83563614_2994781403891160_6736610473828214002_n.jpg to folder a_t_r_a_v__a
Moving file alexa_vn10s1ty429_81834750_1570208686488587_1442450484794514255_n.jp to folder alexa_vn10s1ty429
Moving file shurra.m.lance_96141088_342661823370490_6342263806980952485_n.jpg to folder shurra.m.lance
Moving file anu.m0111_104134441_573701159868969_589828829350351913_n.jpg to folder anu.m0111
```